# Unable to install latest version of Codeblocks

Tags: installation, kubuntu, code-blocks

I am presently using Kubuntu, and now I want to install Codeblocks latest version.

I tried using

```
$ sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

but, it gives me Codeblocks 10.05.

I don't know where is the problem. Earlier I was able to install Codeblocks 12.11 in Ubuntu, why such problem in Kubuntu then?

Answer (score 1):

dear friend the version available on ubuntu repositories is 10.05.
if you want to install 12.11 or 12.12
download it from here

http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries

or use codeblocks PPA

https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ppa/

Answer (score 0):

http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-dbg_12.11-2_i386-debian-stable.tar.bz2
32bit

http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-dbg_12.11-2_amd64-debian-stable.tar.bz2
64bit

download your version, extract it somewhere, find the directory using "cd"-command and write `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and it will be installed.

Comment: Read the notice, before posting links Important note for Ubuntu users: The contrib-plugins package for debian can not be used on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, due to an incomaptible libhunspell-package. Alternatively you can use the Ubuntu repo provided by our user pasgui.